# Turn on video monetisation for YouTube videos uploaded via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I got approved into Youtube Partner Program and my video is eligible for monetisation.

I upload some videos through Data API and when they go live their monetization is turned off by default. Can I change that? I would like it on by default on all videos.

If not, is it possible to programmatically use an API to turn it on using the video_id?

Comment: I dont think thats something that is supported by the api.

Comment: does it mean all creators when they upload videos they need to manually turn on monetisation for them?

Comment: probably I think you also need to consent to the fact that its not including any violations.   These things came way after the youtube api and i dont think they are updating that api anymore.

Comment: no, I don't think it's possible